# How to fill data with specific Header and Number?

Tags: excel, vba

i have a set of data in a column, where 3 rows belongs to one type and next 3 to another(it depends on the header)headers are Article, Journal, Doi
i want to form a table, using the header
condition: should check every 3 row, if one header is missing, i want the result to be NULL and move to the next. i want to do that in order

```
Article      _   Cyclopia Extracts

Journal      _   Planta Medica
DOI          _   10.1055/s-0043-121270
Article      _   Germline Mutations
Journal      _   Human Molecular Genetics
DOI          _   10.1093/hmg/4.12.2233
Article      _   Critical Speed
Journal      _   Vehicle System Dynamics
Article      _   Recycling and Neutral
Journal      _   Journal of Nuclear Materials
DOI          _   10.1016/0022-3115(89)90259-6


Article      _   Cyclopia Extracts  Journal      _   Planta Medica  DOI          _   10.1055/s-0043-121270
Article      _   Germline Mutations Journal      _   Human Molecular Genetics   DOI          _   10.1093/hmg/4.12.2233
Article      _   Critical Speed and Journal      _   Vehicle System Dynamics    Null
Article      _   Recycling and  Journal      _   Journal of Nuclear Materials   DOI          _   10.1016/0022-3115(89)90259-6
```

Comment: What is your programming question?  In addition to VBA or formulas, you could also do this in Power Query

Comment: am new to this and i do not know how to approach this(by which method) so would appreciate lil help.

Comment: I would use either VBA or Power Query.  There will be more of a learning curve than with formulas (and PQ may be easier then VBA), but the result will be more flexible, easier to adapt to other situations, and easier to expand. Once you've gotten a start, if you still have problems, post the code or methods you are using by editing your question. You might also want to read the read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use power query to do this.  The kind of transformation you're talking about is a 'Pivot.'

So, you've got your data in two columns

[image]

You want to add something that will help Excel understand which rows combine to form one record.  You can add a little formula to do this.

```
=IFERROR(IF(B2="Article",A1+1,A1),1)
```

I put this in A2 and then copied it down the column for the whole table.  It basically keeps a count.  Each time the header is 'Article,' the count goes up.

[image]

Select the whole table.  Navigate to the Data tab and click 'From Table/Range'

[image]

This opens the Power Query editor.  Highlight the header column, navigate to the Transform tab, and click 'Pivot' under 'Any Column' group.  In the dialog that pops up, set the Values Column to your 'information' column, and expand "Advanced Options."  Set Aggregate Value Function to Minimum (or maximum, either works).

[image]

Click on OK, then go back to the 'Home' tab and choose 'close and load'.

[image]

Presto!

[image]
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116717/how-to-fill-data-with-specific-header-and-number

Private Range_Headers As Range
Private Range_Data As Range
Private Separ As String

Sub Run_()

    Set Range_Data = Range("$A$1:$A$11")
    Set Range_Headers = Range("$F$1:$H$1")
    Separ = " _ "

    Data_ForEach Range_Data

End Sub

Sub Data_ForEach( _
    r As Range)

    Dim ceLL As Range

    For Each ceLL In r

        With ceLL

            PutIn_Column ceLL.Value

        End With
    Next
End Sub

Sub PutIn_Column( _
    s As String)


    Dim sHead As String, sValu As String

    If InStr(s, Separ) > 0 Then

        sHead = Trim(Split(s, Separ)(0))
        sValu = Trim(Split(s, Separ)(1))

        Inter_Sect _
                Row_Esta(sHead), Column_Esta(sHead), sValu

    End If
End Sub

Function Row_Esta( _
         s As String) _
         As Long

With Range_Headers(1, 1)
    If s = .Value Then
        ' HeadKey
        If .Offset(1, 0).Value = vbNullString Then

            Row_Esta = .Row + 1

        Else
            Row_Esta = .End(xlDown).Row + 1

        End If

    Else

        Row_Esta = .End(xlDown).Row

    End If
End With
End Function

Function Column_Esta( _
         s As String) _
         As Long
'
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range_Headers.Find(s)

    If Not r Is Nothing Then

        Column_Esta = r.Column

    End If
End Function

Function Inter_Sect( _
         lRow As Long, _
         lCol As Long, _
         s As String) _
         As String
'
    If lRow * lCol > 0 Then

        Cells(lRow, lCol).Value = s

    End If
End Function
```